# Can someone explain this notation of a limit?

Tags: limits, notation

What is the explanation/motivation for this notation? tiontion
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a+0}f(x)$$
I understand it should be equivalent to this notation, which seems much more logical (and simpler):
$$\lim_{x\searrow a}f(x)$$

Comment: The notation is of course abusive and thereby confusing. We should be allowed to replace any subexpression by an equal expression in any equation. Thus $a+0=a-0=a$ would "officially" make $\lim_{x\to a+0}=\lim_{x\to a-0}=\lim_{x\to a}$. What shold we think of $\lim_{x\to 0+a}$ or $\lim_{x\to \frac a2+0+\frac a2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always saw this form $$\lim_{x\to a^+}$$

I think the reason behind yours is that it means $x=a+\varepsilon \to a + 0$, i.e. $\varepsilon \to 0$ (meaning you're approaching the point from the positive side)