# Clarification about notation for one-sided limits

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, notation

Is $\lim_{x \to 3-0} f(x)$ the same as $\lim_{x \to 3^-} f(x)$, and is $\lim_{x \to 3+0} f(x)$ the same as $\lim_{x \to 3^+} f(x)$?

Could anyone clarify this for me please? Thanks

Comment: I think your confusion is in the notation? The minus and plus signs that are used to notate a one-sided limit are placed in the "exponent" of the number and, as such, they are not that same as addition or subtraction.

Comment: Where did you come across this? It is well possible this is a notation for a onesided limit too, and means the same. It is also possibly it is some almost trick question.

Comment: @quid well basically it was this question: Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f(-2)=4$ and $f(3)=7$. Let $S:=\{x \in [-2,3]\mid f(x)\geq 5\}$. Then $\alpha:=\inf S$ exists. If $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$, show that:

(a) $-2<\alpha<3$

And in one of the answers I saw: First we show that $\alpha$ is not equal to -2. Indeed, if $\alpha = -2$, then $\lim_{x \to 2+0} f(x) = 4$

Comment: So I wasn't sure what it meant.

Comment: In this case the one-sided limit is meant. No doubt. It is the same as if $2^+$ would be written. It is just another notation.

Comment: @quid Ok, also further down the solution, it is mentioned if $\alpha = 3$ then $\lim_{x \to 3-0} = 7$, here too it means $x \to 3^-$ right?

Comment: Yes. I am in the process of writing a full answer. It could make sense you include the example you gave in a comment in the question itself.

Comment: @Su003 take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786853/can-someone-explain-this-notation-of-a-limit?rq=1) (very similar)

Comment: Thanks!
@quid Also on the solution I found this $\lim_{x \to -2+0} f(x)=4$, Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $\alpha$. This means there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-4|<1/2$ if $-2 \leq x <-2+\delta$. Thus, $f(x)<4.5$ for every $x \in [\alpha, \alpha + \delta)$. Hence $[-2,-2+\delta)$ intersection $S$ is not a null set $\to inf S \geq = -2+\delta$ which is a contradiction. What does the arrow mean here? Does it mean that it implies that $inf S \geq -2+\delta$? Thanks

Comment: I would assume so, though the text-snippet is confusing for me (as it does not seem to follow). could the inequality be reversed?

Comment: @quid you mean $inf S \leq -2+\delta$? Btw, the extra $=$ sign wasn't supposed to be there. It was a typo form me. Sorry.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. Because if $S$ apparently contains some element from $[-2, -2 + \delta )$ then the inf of it is less than $-2 + \delta$. **However** I now see that above you recalled the definition of $S$. It seems that the intersection is the empty set, which implies the assertion on the inf. Note that above it says $f(x)\ge 5$ for $x \in S$ while it is asserted than $f(x)< 4.5$ for $x $ in $[-2, - 2 + \delta)$. So the intersection should be empty.

Comment: @quid so the part of the solution I wrote is correct, right?

Comment: Not completely. You say "is not a null set" but it is a null set, in my opinion.

Comment: @quid Oh, I am so sorry. That was a mistake for my part. It actually is the null set. So yes, the intersection is the null set. So based on this the inequality was be correct, am I right?

Comment: Yes. If it is the nullset the inequality is as  you wrote.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @quid one last thing: when we say $x \in U_{\delta}(\alpha)$ it means $x \in ((\alpha - \delta),(\alpha+\delta))$?

Comment: In your context yes essentially. It would be more precise to say it contains the elements *in the domain* that are at most $\delta$ away from $\alpha$ If you domain is all of the reals you get what you wrote. But if it is something else or only a subset of the reals you would get something else; in the later case the intersection of the domain with the interval you gave.

Comment: @quid Could you please help me here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068082/prove-that-limit-goes-to-inf/1068121#1068121 ? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I am in a rush. I will have a look tomorrow (if it should not be resoveld until then).

Answer (score 2):

$3-0=3+0=3$, so each of the corresponding limits are two sided limits. The other limits, $x\to 3^-$ and $x\to 3^+$, are one sided limits. In general, therefore, they are not the same.

Comment: So basically you mean that the $x \to 3-0$ is the limit approaching 3 from both sides (right and left)? So there's no difference between the $3-0$ and $3+0$?

Comment: @Su003 That is correct. $3+0$ and $3-0$ are numbers and are both equal to 3. $3^-$ and $3^+$ are numbers with additional notation indicating that we are approaching from one side.

Answer (score 2):

The notations $\lim_{x \to a +0}$ and $\lim_{x \to a - 0}$ can be used to signify one-sided limits; the meaning is exactly the same as that of $\lim_{x \to a^+}$ and $\lim_{x \to a^-}$, respectively.

This is a so-called ["abuse of notation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation); one assigns to the string $a+0$ a meaning other than the usual one, "$a$ plus $0$."

The rational is to avoid a double-subscript and the assumption that no-one would normally  write "$a+0$" there to mean the sum of $a$ and $0$, so that the intended meaning can be inferred from context.

Comment: Would you write $a+1+0$, or would you change your mind and in that case write $(a+1)^+$?

Comment: Personally I would not use the notation at all. If I would, I'd go for  adding a parenthesis, like $(a+1)+ 0$. The IMO better abuse of notation is just $a+$ and $a-$. But the linked to neardupe gives a good reason for writing $+0$, one consider $a+ \epsilon$ and $\epsilon $ to $0$ which is good for recalling which is which.

Comment: I wouldn't even call the latter abuse of notation. $a+$ and $a-$ have no standard meaning so there's no problem in writing that to indicate the one sided limit. If I saw the 3+0 on a student's paper, though, I'd mark it wrong unless they explicitly explained that that was what the notation meant.

Comment: One could argue it is an ill-formed and thus AoN. But I agree it is somewhat different. I agree the notation can cause misundersting. I was initially not certain myself and it *could* have been that somebody wanted to test student's understanding of the different notations in a different way, but given the context later given, it seems clear that the 1-sided limit is meant there. Note I wrote: it *can* mean what I said.

Comment: Using $a+\epsilon$ and letting $\epsilon\to 0$ is even worse in my opinion. $x\to a+\epsilon$ followed by $\epsilon\to 0$ is exactly the same as the two sided limit $x\to a$, unless $\epsilon\to 0^+$.

Comment: I did not mean this as a formal expression/definition just as a help to recall "which is which" of the plus and minus. And, often $\epsilon$ is positive in this context. Yet again I do not wish promote this notation. I merely report and rationalize what some people apparently do.