# Prove that limit goes to inf

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that $f(x), f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ are all positive for each $x \in \mathbb R$. Apply the MVT to $f$ on each interval $[n,n+1]$ for $n=1,2, 3,\dots$ and show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$.

I posted a similar question before but this time I have to solve it by applying MVT. I have no idea how applying MVT to the intervals would help here. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: The fact that $f'$ is positive tells you the function is increasing.  But in order to show the limit is infinity you'd have to show it grows faster than some function which tends to infinity.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang ok, in this case both $f$ anf $f'$ are increasing. But I am not sure how to apply the MVT on the intervals :/

Answer (score 2):

For each $n$, let $n<x_{n}<n+1$ be such that $f(n+1)-f(n)=f'(x_{n})$. Since that $f''>0$,we have that $f'$ is strictly increasing, and therefore, $(f'(x_{n}))$ is an increasing (and positive) sequence.

We have $f(n)-f(1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(f(i+1)-f(i))=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f'(x_{i})\longrightarrow +\infty$.

So,  $f(n)\longrightarrow +\infty$.

Now, if $(a_{n})$ is a sequence diverging to $+\infty$, deduce that $f(a_{n})\longrightarrow +\infty$ using the fact that $f$ is increasing

Comment: so to show that $f(a_n) \to + \infty$, do we have to show first that f is not bounded above?

Comment: @Su003: no, that comes for free once you establish Nahuel's claim.